Поворот игрока при повороте с обьектом
Как сделать так, чтобы при касании определенного объекта игрок (с какой бы он стороны не находился) поворачивался строго в одну сторону?
Например, если игрок идет сверху (2д проекция) то при касании с объектом поворачивался влево (относительно камеры?)
transform.rotation.z (0, 0, -90);
Пробовал таким образом - не получается (игроки относительно камеры идут в разном направлении)
